# C# facebook post without token

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm developing a C# desktop app and I want to make it to post something on a facebook wall using Facebook C# SDK. It is possible to post on a user's wall or on a page without asking permission or is a must to use a token access? If yes, could someone give me an example?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No (of course) it is not possible to post on a user's wall without the user's permission. You need the `publish_stream` permission: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I post user's id or name on a page of mine, this post it will appear on his wall?

Comment: Not quite sure about that one. I don't think it will, the risk is a lot of spam in that case.